# How do I convince a subprocess that it is being run in a terminal?

Tags: c, linux, tty

So I have a program that checks if it is running in a terminal using `isatty`. Now I'm calling it as a subprocess from a non-terminal program, but I still want to make it think that it is running in a terminal. Is there some libc function that does this?

Comment: No, but you could use a pseudo-tty (pty).

Comment: If you don't want to set up a pty, you can execute a wrapper program that does it, such as `script` or `unbuffer` (from `expect`).

Comment: Yet another way is to write a wrapper library and use LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten about ptys. Thanks!